# Add a stackoverflow URL builder

Tags: feature-request, tags, hyperlinks

I am using some custom URLs in order to follow my favorite tags.

Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/'c'%23%20or%20'asp.net-mvc'%20or%20'sql-server'%20or%20'jde'%20or%20'cognos'%20or%20'jdedwards'%20or%20'entity-framework'%20or%20'asp.net'

Wouldn't it be useful to have a small utility in our profile or on the sidebar to add the tags we want and create the url?

**In short, I want to be able to have separate urls that will show questions of a specific "area of interest"**

Comment: The 'search' box builds this for you; you do have to type in the `[..]` brackets for each tag, but `[c] or [asp.net-mvc] or [sql-server] or [jde] or [cognos] or [jdedwards] or [entity-framework] or [asp.net]` typed into the search box works, and can be extended there.

Comment: it works!!!! i guess it was RTFM somewhere..Put it as an answer to be more accessible if u like..thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Funny that you used my tags :)))) luck... :)

Comment: No luck about that; I specifically used your sample URL. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search box will produce that URL for you, provided you use only tags and `or`. Put each tag into square brackets:

`[c] or [asp.net-mvc] or [sql-server] or [jde] or [cognos] or [jdedwards] or [entity-framework] or [asp.net]`

You'll notice that the searchbox for your URL already comes pre-filled with that query, you can add more tags to it later on. Bookmark the resulting URL.

The searchbox has a lower character limit than the actual tag limit; if you run into the search box limit you'll have to manually extend the URL. You can also use *wildcard* tags:

```
[jde*]
```

will match all tags that start with `jde`, including `jdedwards` for example.

Answer (score -2):

On your screen's right side on the home page of Stackoverflow,near to favourite tags,click on edit and then add your tags

---

[image]

Comment: that means that after that my default view will be only for them? Also what if i want a subset of them? that was primarily the reason to ask

Comment: no,not default view...you will have the same the normal view of the page as before..but along with your favourite tags highlighted by a yellowish backg  round...see the image(the third question is not of my favourite tags)

Comment: This doesn't build the search though.

Comment: Yes this is not what i want..I want to be able to see all questions for a specific "area of interest"..